# in C# .net framework 2.0 how can i unzip a .zip file to a specified directory and have it wait untill it is done before moveing on

Tags: c#, zip

i have a .zip file that my application needs to extract, and run how would i go about doing this? it needs to extract Programs\Test\Build.zip to the directory:

```
string tempFolder = System.Environment.GetEvironmentVariable("HomeDrive");
```

then it needs to wait till its finished, then run the exe "Compile.exe" that was extracted, ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Well, for one thing you could extract it in code, using [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/).

There's a [sample](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/SharpZipLib-Zip-Samples.ashx#Unpack_a_Zip_with_full_control_over_the_operation_3) for unpacking a complete zip file.

Once that's done, just use [`Process.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92699yzt.aspx) to launch the executable.

Comment: well its just for one single .zip and alot of that looks confusing and unnecessarily.

Comment: @NightsEvil: Why does it matter whether it's a single zip file or not? How would that affect how complex the code is going to be?

Comment: @jon well i dont know im still new to all this. I just figured that if it could be simplified, or cut down some id bring it up.

Comment: @Nights: You could cut down that sample a bit since it does some extra things (like for example skipping directories etc) but if your zip file don't contain any directories you could probably copy that code just as it is (assuming that's ok license wise) into your app and all you'd have to do would be to call it with those simple parameters.

Comment: ok and as for the password part would that work for a .zip file thats passworded made with 7-zip? (.zip NOT .7z)

Comment: @NightsEvil: I'd expect so; I think the password protection is standardised in the zip format - but the easiest way to find out is probably just to try it.

Comment: wow please be patient with me as i am a noobie and im trying to learn this all my self with no 1 else to bounce ideas off in real life, and this is just way confusing for me, i just wanna extract a .zip file to a folder LOL why does that have to be so complicated?

Answer (score 1):

I have used http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/

Lots of examples here: http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CS-Examples&referringTitle=Examples

Answer (score 1):

```
//  C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\vjslib.dll
    // <add assembly="vjslib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
    public class ZipWriter : Stream {
        public ZipWriter() { dest = new MemoryStream(); }
        public ZipWriter(Stream owner) { dest = owner; }
        public ZipWriter(Stream owner, string FileName) { dest = owner; AddFile(FileName); }



        public void AddFile(string FileName) {
            if (writer == null) writer = new zipwriter(this);                
            if (writer.az == null) writer.az = new java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream(writer); else writer.az.closeEntry();
            writer.az.putNextEntry(new java.util.zip.ZipEntry(FileName));

        }

        public byte[] ToArray() { finalize(); return ((MemoryStream)dest).ToArray(); }


        public void finalize()
        { /*Закрыть архив*/
            if (writer.az == null) return; writer.az.closeEntry(); writer.az.finish(); writer.az = null;
        }
        public override long Length { get { finalize(); return dest.Length; } }

        /*Забрать zip*/


        public Stream dest;

        class zipwriter : java.io.OutputStream
        {                
            public ZipWriter parent;
            public java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream az;
            public override void write(sbyte[] buffer, int offset, int count){ 
                if (count<=0) return;
                byte[] dest = new byte[offset + count];
                Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, offset, dest, offset, count);
                parent.dest.Write( dest, offset,count);              
            }
            public override void write(int b) {  parent.dest.WriteByte((byte)b); }
            public zipwriter(ZipWriter owner) { parent = owner; }

        }
        zipwriter writer;
        long      position;
        public override bool CanRead { get {return false; } }            
        public override bool CanSeek { get {return false;} }            
        public override bool CanWrite { get {return true;} }


        public override long Position { get {  return position;  } set { position = value;} }            
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing){  }
        public override void Flush() { dest.Flush(); }            
        public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count){ return 0;}

        public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin) {  return position; }

        public override void SetLength(long value) { }

        public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count){                                 
            if (count<=0) return;                
             sbyte[] dest = new sbyte[offset + count];
             Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, offset, dest, offset, count);
             writer.az.write(dest, offset, count);
             position += count;                
           }
       }


       /* Example:
          ZipWriter ZipStream = new ZipWriter();
          ZipStream.AddFile("1.txt");
          ...  ZipStream.WriteByte(65);

         Response.Clear();
         Response.ContentType = "application/force-download";
         Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",   "attachment; filename=1.zip");
         Response.BinaryWrite(ZipStream.ToArray());
         Response.End();          
       */
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using SharpZipLib as described [here](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/). It's easy to use and I think it's synchronous by default. See [this](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/SharpZipLib-Zip-Samples.ashx) page for samples on how to use it.

And then just execute it using `Process.Start`